# How can in replace values in array without any function?

Tags: java, arrays

**I tried to do this**

This is the **original** array .

```
String [] array = {"A" , "B" , "C" , "1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5"};
```

Having trouble doing it,to replace it to this.
(without functions).

```
String [] array = {"1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "A" , "B" , "C"};
```

**Thanks for all.**

Comment: Suppose this is a homework question. Take a look at one of many sorting algorithms, like quicksort: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Without further explanations, and with the onyl need of "Not containing functions", you  can simply put the values in the array:

```
array[0] = "1";
array[1] = "2";
...
```

Or even simply:

```
array = {"1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "A" , "B" , "C"};
```

Comment: And with loops it can be ?

Comment: @Asras Yes. But without more informations, it won't be really different.

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] array = {"A" , "B" , "C" , "1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5"};
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Will give you the expected result.

Comment: He said `without functions` though.

Comment: I thought he meant `java.util.function`.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot declare an array again once it has been declared plus and an "array constant" , meaning { ... }, can only be used for initialization not to assign values to an existing array. You can change them one by one or by using a for loop.